# Minimum Page Table Size for Process?

Tags: c, memory, virtual-memory, tlb, page-tables

I was learning about Page Table and Virtual Memory, My professor showed the following image:

[image]

and asked what's the minimum size for the page table where L1=L2=256

I answered it's 256 since L1 is always allocated (A register is pointing to it) and all the pointers inside of it can be NULL.

He said this isn't correct and it should be 512 where L1 is allocated and at least one of the pointers isn't NULL.

I didn't get that, why one of them MUST be pointing to some page table?

Comment: Can someone kindly help before my exam?

Comment: How can you have a process with no memory?

Comment: @RaymondChen who said so? I said only L1 is allocated.... If the process was just created it can be that none of L1 entries is allocated...

Comment: Where is the instruction pointer in this memoryless process? It'll crash the moment it tries to execute its first instruction. While this is technically legal, it isn't very useful.